# Beta Testing Request?

Tags: discussion

Can we request or post a request for beta testers sign up in here? New to this section, used stack Exchange for work work but now using it for game development. Little new to these rules

Comment: You can probably do that on gamedev.net

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't ask for beta testers here.

Check out the [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what kind of things you can ask about here, and what you can't ask about. Further, questions about the site should go here in meta, questions about game development go on the main site.